# After importing an obj file, I cant enable smooth shading, or at least it doesn't do anything

Tags: objects

Blender version: 2.8

Windows 32-bit

Click [Here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/505741073205690380/650366002026119239/King_model.blend) to get the project file, you need in order to help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question needs a bit more meat on the bone.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Every verts are duplicated, you have to remove the duplicates. Select everything in Edit Mode then choose Vertex>Merge Vertices>By Distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem you have here is that the entire model is ripped. If the mesh is not connected cant be smoothed out. In order to solve this, you have to select everything and remove doubles or as it is called now (merge by distance) by pressing Alt+M. Done that the mash will be messed up, with everything still selected press Shift+N to recalculate the Normals. Now if you press smooth shading the mesh should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!!!!